# Add a parent to posts in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, parent, posts

i'm setting up a premate theme but it has a weird template for the blog main page.
i found a solution to remove the blog page from "reading" section in wordpress but i want now to add a parent "/blog/" to all my posts.

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Not having hierarchy is sort of the defining feature of 'post' vs 'page'. They are the same object with different features toggled – features like 'hierarchy'.

The hierarchy functionality only works among the same 'post_type', so all 'page' 'post_type' can be related to one another, but not to 'post' 'post_type', or any other custom post type. (Confusing because 'post' is a 'post_type'.)

All this to say there is not a clean solution for this.

Perhaps there is another way to accomplish your goal, like WP_Query().